# X509Certificate Serial Number as Byte Array? C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, arrays, x509certificate

What would be the best way of converting a serial number from an [X509certifiacte2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) to a byte array (for storage) and back?

Comment: @user384706, appologies for my ommision, C#. Storage on the file system in a binary blob with a bunch of other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two extension methods to convert a hexadecimal string to a byte array and back:

```
static byte[] ParseAsBytes(static string s)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length / 2)
                     .Select(i => byte.Parse(s.Substring(i * 2, 2), 
                                             NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
                     .ToArray();
}

static string ToHexString(this byte[] buffer)
{
    return string.Concat(buffer.Select(i => i.ToString("X2")));
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var input = "0001020304050607";

var bytes = input.ParseAsBytes();
// bytes == new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 }

var result = bytes.ToHexString();
// result == "0001020304050607"
```

(For more efficient implementations, have a look the code of the internal System.Security.Util.Hex class using a tool like Reflector. These are used by the SerialNumber property to convert an internal byte[] field in the X509Certificate class to a hexadecimal string.)

Answer (score 0):

[System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) handles converting strings to/from byte array.  You should be able to do the following (assuming you're using ASCII for text encoding):

```
byte[] serial = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x509_cert.SerialNumber);
```

and to get the byte[] serial back into a string:

```
string x509_serial = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(serial);
```

Comment: The SerialNumber property returns a hexadecimal string representation of the serial number. Your code converts the string to bytes, but not to the bytes represented by the string.

Comment: I don't want the decoded characters, serial numbers on certificates are stored as binary, and converted to Hex for humans to read. For some reason .Net doesn't like giving you the binary version, and gives the hex chars mashed together instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] data)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [X509Certificate.GetSerialNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getserialnumber?view=net-5.0). This method is accessible from `X509Certificate2` as well.

Please, be wary about bytes order:

> Returns the serial number of the X.509v3 certificate as an array of bytes in little-endian order.